# Handle dynamic Number of Listboxes with Strongly Typed Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a way to handle a dynamic number of Listboxes and don't seem to be able to find the answer searching SO or Google.

Considering the following ViewModel

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedOptions { get; set; } 
}

public class Option
{
    public OptionType Type { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OptionType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This can then be presented using the following razor view

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.IndexViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedOptions, new MultiSelectList(Model.Options, "Id", "Name"), new {Multiple = "multiple"})
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
}
```

and handled using the following action methods

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel();
    var colourType = new OptionType {Id = 0, Name = "Colour"};
    var shapeType = new OptionType {Id = 1, Name = "Shape"};
    model.Options = new List<Option>
        {
            CreateOption(0, "Red", colourType),
            CreateOption(1, "Green", colourType),
            CreateOption(2, "Circle", shapeType),
            CreateOption(2, "Square", shapeType)
        };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
    //Do something with the posted model
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private static Option CreateOption(int id, string name, OptionType colourType)
{
    return new Option
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = name,
        Type = colourType
    };
}
```

If I were to separate the `Option`s Based on their `OptionType` into multiple list boxes by changing the model and views as so

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Option>> Options { get; set; }

    //public List<int> SelectedOptions { get; set; } 
}
```

and

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.IndexViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var optList in Model.Options)
        {
            <li>
                @optList.Key : @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedOptions, new MultiSelectList(optList.Value, "Id", "Name"), new { Multiple = "multiple" })
            </li>   
        }
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
}
```

And modify the supporting controller methods as so

```
    public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel();
    model.Options = new Dictionary<string, List<Option>>
        {
            {"Colour", CreateColourList()},
            {"Shape", CreateShapeList()}
        };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}


private static List<Option> CreateColourList()
{
    var colourType = new OptionType { Id = 0, Name = "Colour" };

    return new List<Option>
        {
            CreateOption(0, "Red", colourType),
            CreateOption(1, "Green", colourType),
        };
}
private static List<Option> CreateShapeList()
{
    var shapeType = new OptionType { Id = 1, Name = "Shape" };
    return new List<Option>
        {
            CreateOption(2, "Circle", shapeType),
            CreateOption(2, "Square", shapeType)
        };
}
private static Option CreateOption(int id, string name, OptionType colourType)
{
    return new Option
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = name,
        Type = colourType
    };
}
```

How would I define the Selected options in the view model so that it binds in the HttpPost Index Action?

Also as an extra i would like to know how to change the SelectedOptions type to contain Option instances rather than integers but initially this isn't too important, a working solution with integers would help ease my head ache.

**EDIT: Just to clarify, while I have defined the Options explicitly in the example above, in the actual code these are actually loaded from a database and there could be any number of `Option`s and and number of `OptionType`s**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedValues { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class IndexViewModel
{
    public List<MyViewModel> Options { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will populate and pass to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel();
    model.Options = new[]
    {
        new MyViewModel { Key = "Colour", Options = CreateColourList() },
        new MyViewModel { Key = "Shape", Options = CreateShapeList() },
    }.ToList(); 
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in the view you would use this view model to generate the proper markup:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ul>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Options[i].Key)
                @Model.Options[i].Key
                :
                @Html.ListBoxFor(
                    model => model.Options[i].SelectedValues,  
                    new MultiSelectList(Model.Options[i].Options, "Id", "Name")
                )
            </li>   
        }
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
}
```

Now when the form is submitted, your HttpPost action will get the corresponding `IndexViewModel` instance properly bound and containing the `Key` and the `SelectedValues` collection for each group of options.

Comment: I need to stop coding at ridiculous times, this makes so much sense I have no idea why I couldn't grasp it! Thanks Darin!